# How can I reset checkpoints in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

I am reading table in pyspark

```
df = spark.readStream.format("delta").load("mySourceTable")
```

And I write it using

```
df.writeStream.format("delta").outputMode("append").option("checkpointLocation", "/_checkpoints/myOutputTable").start("myOutputTable")
```

My question is how can I remove all the checkpoints so that pyspark reads `mySourceTable` from the beginning, instead of from where it was last read?

Thank you.

I don't know how to remove the checkpoints in `"/_checkpoints/myOutputTable").start("myOutputTable")`

Comment: add this readstream option `.option("startingOffsets","earliest")` ??!!

Comment: @eshirvana [the guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html) mentions "For streaming queries, this only applies when a new query is started, and that resuming will always pick up from where the query left off." Also, looks like the `startingOffsets` option is only implemented for the Kafka sources and doesn't work if a Delta table is used as source.

Comment: hmm... right , on the second thought, if you wanna start reading from beginning everytime, then why do you need to stream deltalake?  batch read them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't know how to remove the checkpoints in "/_checkpoints/myOutputTable").start(myOutputTable")

After stopping the Spark application, you can go directly to the `checkpointLocation` directory on your file system (or wherever the table is stored e.g. S3) and move/delete it.

When you then restart the Spark application it will process `mySourceTable` from the beginning.